# How can I fix Invoke()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, invoke

I wanted to run test and part A at the same time.

However, after the test was fully executed, part A below was activated.

I think this is because of `test.Invoke()`.

How Can I fix it?

```
public static void work()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    throw new TimeoutException();
}

private static void SafeExecute(Action test)
{
    try
    {
        test.Invoke();
        //Do something - part A
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        //Do something - part B
    }

}
```

Comment: `test.Invoke()` will execute synchronously. You can use `test.BeginInvoke()` to execute the delegate asynchronously (even if though that is a really archaic approach). But, your question is unclear. Given all the information on Stack Overflow and on the web generally, how is it that you haven't found _any_ advice anywhere that would help you know how to run the code concurrently? And even if you had, do you _only_ want "part A" to run concurrently? Or is it okay for the `SafeExecute()` method to return before the `test` delegate has finished? And what's `work()` got to do with _any_ of this?

Answer (score 1):

To run it asynchronously you need to use `Task` class:

```
TaskFactory.StartNew(test);
```